# Duplicate Request Virtual Machine Azure

Tags: web-services, azure

I have a WebService running in a Virtual Machine, when I try include one register from the application, I'm receiving 3 requests and duplicating.

I have migrated a service to microsoft azure-cloud-services and start getting triplicate POST request from an Android APP client. Web container used : Tomcat8 (I have tested on 7 too) Rest api: jersey Problem: we have a rest service which is consumed by mobile client (android app), and for unknown reason POSTs (only POSTs) requests are going trice (3x). This is not our code, so when i checked the logs, I've notice that 3+ hibernate sessions are being created. Also I saw that hibernate sessions are being opened in a filter that is there in order to set service charset.

Comment: You'll need to give more info than that. As it stands, there's no way to know what's going on.

Comment: We need more info on this one

Answer (score 0):

actually, I'm who is working on this so I can give more details.
Web container used : Tomcat8 (I have tested on 7 too)
Rest api: jersey
problem: we have a  rest service which is consumed by mobile client (android app), and for unknown reason POSTs (only POSTs) requests are going trice (3x). This is not our code, so when i checked the logs, I've notice that 3+ hibernate sessions are being created. Also I saw that hibernate sessions are being opened in a filter that is there in order to set service charset.

Comment: This would be better if it was included in the original question.